# How to upload a file together with other text inputs without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I use the code below to upload a file successfully without refreshing the page. What I want now is to add one text input field for the title of the file and one textarea to describe the file, but I am having difficulty doing that. It is giving me 'undefined index' error. What should I add to my code below to upload the file, text input and the textarea?

**HTML**

```
<form action="trash_one.php" method="post" id="uploadForm">
    <div id="targetLayer">No Image</div>
    <div id="uploadFormLayer">
    <label >Upload Image</label><br>
    <input type="file" class="inputFile" name="userImage" id="userImage">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btnSubmit">
</form>
<div>
```

**EXPECTED HTML FORM**

Text input and textarea added

```
<form action="trash_one.php" method="post" id="uploadForm">
    <div id="targetLayer">No Image</div>
    <div id="uploadFormLayer">
    <input type="text" name="img_name">
    <label >Upload Image</label><br>
    <input type="file" class="inputFile" name="userImage" id="userImage">
    <textarea name="description" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btnSubmit">
</form>
<div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "trash_one.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#targetLayer").html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
        }
    });
}));
});
```

**PHP**

This script uploads only the file

```
if(is_array($_FILES)){
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])){
        $sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = "imagess/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)){
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" />
        <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code worked for me, try doing `print_r($_POST);` it should show you that your data has come through.

Comment: Of course my code works. What I want to do is to add one text input field and textarea to the form. If I add these fields, what amendment should I do on my PHP script and javascript so as to upload all the data?

Comment: So you have the file data storing working, just get the other data through `$_POST`. so `$name = $_POST['img_name']; $description = $_POST['description'];`.

Comment: `var_dump` $_POST and $_FILES. You'll get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is already working like you want to. Just take a look at the `$_POST` array instead of the `$_FILES` array. The post array contains all the text field contents. the files array contains uploaded files.